# Replacing alternative letters in a string to either "!" or "?"

Tags: javascript, string

This

I'm able to return T!d!y. But i need T!d?y. I'm new to JS and I cant figure it out =(

```
    function change(str) {
        newString = str.split("");
        for (let i = 1; i < newString.length - 1; i+=2) {
                newString[i] = "!";
                //newString[i] = "?";    
         }    
         return(newString.join("")); }

console.log(change("Teddy")); should return T!d?y
```

Comment: Your title is confusing.  You likely meant "**alternating** letters", not _alternative_ letters.  Even better, say "every second letter" or "every other letter".

Comment: Please don't edit questions to change their meaning in a way that invalidates answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo to check whether the `i` being iterated over is one of the 3-7-11 sequence or the 1-5-9 sequence - then you can determine which character to insert.

```js
function change(str) {
  const arr = str.split("");
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) {
    arr[i] = i - 1 % 4 === 0
      ? "!"
      : "?";
  }
  return arr.join("");
}

console.log(change("Teddy"));
```

Also remember

- Declare your variables - doing `newString =` without a `const` (or something) before it implicitly creates a global variable, which is very often not what you want
- `.split` returns an array; `newString` is not an accurate description of what the variable contains (perhaps instead call it `arr` or `newArray` or `characters`, or something like that)

Comment: I am trying to return a string. Will .split make it an return an array?

Comment: `.join('')` will turn an array into a string, so it's fine. Turn the string into an array, change the array, then join the array back into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check and update variable to be replaced.

Few pointers:

- When looping, you will have to loop till last character. `i < arr.length - 1` will cause issues for certain scenarios.

```js
function change(str) {
  const possibilities = [ "!", "?", "*" ];
  let index = 0;
  let newString = str.split("");
  for (let i = 1; i < newString.length ; i += 2) {
    newString[i] = possibilities[index % possibilities.length];
    index++
  }
  return (newString.join(""));
}

console.log(change("Teddy"));
console.log(change("Javascript"));
```